# Rendering escaped HTML content into HTML in DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I have a escaped html . I want this to be rendered as HTML components using js or jquery. Any Idea?

Html to render
`"&lt;strong&gt;Direct Cost Savings, Oracle CRM ReplacementÂ &lt;/strong&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;x users, y portal users&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Integrations: Cisco (CTI), Cognos &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Replacements: Oracle CRM (on-premise), RightNow&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;First of five phased deployments completed&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;"`

Comment: Look at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` to get the brackets output by first rendering the `&lt;` etc, and set that text as the html source:

```
var container = $('#render-target');
container.html(htmlToRender);
container.html(container.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#item').html($("<div/>").html(yourString).text());
```